# Jquery button click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

seems like a simple issue but the solutions to the other problem don't seem to work from me.

Trying to trigger a AJAX request from a button click but it doesn't seem to be firing.

example HTML

```
<button class="remove_weight_button" id="15">x</button>
```

javascript

```
$(".remove_weight_button").click(function(){
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "weight_tracker_process.php",
        data: {
            weight_id: button_id,
            action: "remove"
        },
        success: function(){
            getWeightData();
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("data removal error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: First things first, Do you see any errors in the console?, is it reaching the handler (if not is it wrapped in document.ready), do you see any js error or network error in the console?

Comment: Are you sure the javascript is being run _after_ the button is loaded?  That's a common error.

Comment: try to add a prevent default at the top of your function

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The code you have works fine in fiddle.  Is your button being dynamically rendered through AJAX after the initial page load?

Use

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove_weight_button", function(){
```

instead of

```
$(".remove_weight_button").click(function(){
```

Comment: ah of course, yep you're right it's being loaded by ajax. How does the above fix this?

Comment: @user2803072 The ".click" event you're using only looks for elements that were drawn during the initial page load.  The "on" event looks for elements in the current state of the page

Comment: Alternatively `$(".remove_weight_button").live("click", function() { ...` if the page is loaded dynamically and you are using an *older* version of jQuery. The key is the `click` doesn't notice dynamically loaded DOM elements as you mentioned.

Comment: @LloydBanks, your explanation is actually incorrect. You might want to read up on [event delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). This code works specifically because of the selector argument (the second argument in the on method). You can easily create an example that proves your explanation wrong: $(".remove_weight_button").on( "click", function(){...}) . The 'on' method is NOT looking "for elements in the current state of the page," as you stated. The event is just being binded to the document, and then 'delegated' to the selector ".remove_weight_button" element.

Comment: This solution saved me .. I was trying for 1 hour to just fire an event with JQuery and could not do it.

Comment: @Mike.MKrallaProductions You're confused about the parent / child relationship.  The `document` is the parent element in the example above.  It could be any element that is encapsulating `.remove_weight_button`.

Comment: I understand that the document is the parent element in the example. Your explanation in the comment is wrong, as I pointed out. You specifically state *The "on" event looks for elements in the current state of the page.* This is simply **not true**, and could mislead developers. The 'on' function has nothing to do with elements on the the current state of the page, the **delegation/selector argument**  `".remove_weight_button"` (second arg) does, just as I pointed out. The fact that the `click` function does not take the **delegation argument** is the real reason you have to use `on`.

Comment: @Mike.MKrallaProductions This is an encapsulation of the logic so that it's easier for people to understand.  Conveying a message correctly is much more important than copying and pasting text from the jQuery website and trying to prove that you know what you are doing based solely on that

Comment: This solution saved me too. Spent about 2 hours but finally with this small piece of code was able to achieve what I wanted as my list items were being dynamically rendered using ajax call.

Comment: Thank you, I ran into similar problem